# BLE Gatt status 133 in onCharacteristicWrite

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm  trying to connect to a BLE device that has one characteristic to write requests for data and another that sends notifications with said data. I'm able to write to the CCCD with no problems, but when I write to the write characteristic, 9 times out of 10 I get a gatt status 133 error. I've checked the properties, set the write type, and added a 600ms wait before each command, but nothing seems to be helping.

```
public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
                    super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
                    Log.d(MY_TAG, "Wrote " + descriptor.getUuid() + " with status " + status);
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        Log.d(MY_TAG, "Write Successful");
                        enableAllNotifications();
                        try {
                            writeData(new byte[] {4, 0, 36});
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(MY_TAG, "Write failed");
                    }
                }
            };
```

enableAllNotifications() just sets notifications on my end, since onCharacteristicChanged() only seems to be called when both have notifications set.

```
private void writeData(byte[] message) throws InterruptedException {
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mainActivity.deviceServices.get(0)
                .getCharacteristic(ActiCharacteristicUuids.WriteUUID);
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        characteristic.setValue(message);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(600);
        bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
```

```
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
        Log.d(MY_TAG, "Inside onCharactersiticWrite with status: " + status);
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
             Log.d(MY_TAG, "Write failed");
             retryWrite(characteristic);
        } else {
             Log.d(MY_TAG, "Write Successful");
             gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
}
```

I don't know if this is helpful, but I've been testing with a Samsung Galaxy S10+ and a Samsung Galaxy S8 Active, and both seem to have these issues. I don't have another device to test if this is just a Samsung issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this worked, but I had called writeDescriptor inside the main activity. For some reason, changing that call to readDescriptor, and then writing to the CCC inside readDescriptor solved the problem. I guess it was a threading issue? So, if anyone else is experiencing this problem, try to have all of your writes (including writeDescriptor and writeCharacteristic) on the same thread.

Comment: Inserting a random sleep will not solve any issues correctly. The Bluetooth stack doesn't require any particular calls do be done on a specific thread. The only thing that matters, usually, is that you may only have one outstanding GATT request at a time.